# Only one coupon per customer in magento shoppin cart price rule

Tags: magento-1.9, php, cart, coupon

I am using Magento ver. 1.9.2.0 and I have the following issue with coupon codes. I have set up a shopping cart rule which uses a coupon code. I want customers to be able to use this coupon only once, so I set up Uses per Customer to 1. but this rule not work customer use many time same coupon code 
and i have set the discount amount 0.

find the screenshot below

[image]

[image]

Comment: What if you set "uses per coupon" to 1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First thing **why you are setting code for Discount Amount 0?** although you get code success message but your code is not applied on order as its not affecting any price of the cart. That's the reason it is not recorded as used code for the customer which allow to use code multiple times.If you open your placed order with this code at either customer side or admin side you will notice that your order is not showing code information. where as if you change the discount amount it will work correctly. so the question is again **why you are setting code for Discount Amount 0**.

Comment: because i am using the extension in this extension buy x product get Y free using coupon code